# installed a jetty server. Do I need other configurations for it to run php/java code?

Tags: java, php, jetty, push-notification

I have previously installed xampp on my remote linux server. So I already have php pre-compiled. Java also. I installed a jetty server. Do I need other configuration to it to run both PHP and JSP?

I want to use JSP and jetty server instead of PHP and apache for scaling issues regarding a notification system that I will soon apply. Any feedback on this descision will be apprecitied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See their [documentation for PHP support](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+and+PHP).

Comment: That's quite out of date documentation for a very old version of Jetty. It's probably not going to solve Woho87's problem.